# My windows 10 laptop can't see 5Ghz SSID on my laptop, even though my wireless adapter supports it

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking

Help! My wireless router broadcasts both 2.4 and 5 ghz ssids, and my android phone can pick up both fine. My laptop, however, only sees 2.4 ghz.

Here's the results of "netsh wlan show drivers" in cmd:

```
Interface name: Wi-Fi 2

Driver                    : Qualcomm Atheros AR956x Wireless Network Adapter
Vendor                    : Qualcomm Atheros Communications Inc.
Provider                  : Microsoft
Date                      : 3/26/2016
Version                   : 3.0.2.201
INF file                  : athw8x.inf
Type                      : Native Wi-Fi Driver
Radio types supported     : 802.11b 802.11g 802.11n
FIPS 140-2 mode supported : Yes
802.11w Management Frame Protection supported : Yes
Hosted network supported  : Yes
Authentication and cipher supported in infrastructure mode:
                            Open            None
                            Open            WEP-40bit
                            Open            WEP-104bit
                            Open            WEP
                            WPA-Enterprise  TKIP
                            WPA-Personal    TKIP
                            WPA2-Enterprise TKIP
                            WPA2-Personal   TKIP
                            Vendor defined  TKIP
                            WPA2-Enterprise Vendor defined
                            Vendor defined  Vendor defined
                            WPA-Enterprise  CCMP
                            WPA-Personal    CCMP
                            WPA2-Enterprise CCMP
                            Vendor defined  CCMP
                            WPA2-Enterprise Vendor defined
                            Vendor defined  Vendor defined
                            WPA2-Personal   CCMP
                            Vendor defined  Vendor defined
Authentication and cipher supported in ad-hoc mode:
                            Open            None
                            Open            WEP-40bit
                            Open            WEP-104bit
                            Open            WEP
                            WPA2-Personal   CCMP
                            Vendor defined  Vendor defined
Wireless Display Supported: Yes (Graphics Driver: Yes, Wi-Fi Driver: Yes)
```

Here's the advanced settings tab of my wireless adapter:

[image]

Comment: Can you update your question/tags to include your OS?

Comment: @Kinnectus just did.

Comment: Why do you thing your wireless adapter supports it? It doesn’t support 11a, which is a strong indicator it doesn’t do 5 GHz.

Comment: 802.11n and ac support 5GHz......

Comment: @user912904 install the latest atheros driver.

Comment: @Moab: 802.11n supports 5 GHz but _does not require it_ – there exist many 2.4-only devices with 802.11n support. (And OP's device info doesn't mention 802.11ac support, so that's not very relevant...)

Answer (score 2):

The Atheros AR9565 supports only 2.4GHz.  There is no 5GHz support for this card.

Radio types supported     : 802.11b 802.11g 802.11n

802.11b/g/n are only supported in 2.4GHz band.

If your card listed 802.11a/b/g/n/ac, then you'd have a card that supported both bands (2.4GHz and 5GHz).

If you bond your channels (although not recommended in 2.4GHz, but totally doable), you may get an 802.11n rate of 150.

Here is your adapter specification: https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Qualcomm_Atheros_QCWB335

And here is the WiFi Alliance certificate for this adapter (2015):
https://www.wi-fi.org/content/search-page?keys=QCA9565

Click on the little certificate at the bottom left and it will download the full certificate for you.

Comment: how can an ASUS laptop bought in 2015 does not support 5ghz wireless internet ? I find that hard to believe.

Comment: Manufacturers use 2.4GHz wireless adapters to save cost.  What is the model number of your laptop?  Don't take my word for it, see your adapter specification: https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Qualcomm_Atheros_QCWB335

Comment: I feel like I've answered your question, even though it's not what you want to hear.  Please mark my answer as answered.

Comment: are you certain that this card does not support 5 ghz ?

Comment: Send me your laptop model number - for a triple check!

Comment: @user912904, pythonian is correct. I have a bag full of the mini-pcie version, they are 2.4 only.